# How to identify the string where it contains multiple words

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements, string-search

Data frame column text with datatype string contains sentences, I am looking to extract the rows which contains certain words irrespective of place in which they occur.

For ex:

```
Column
Cat and mouse are the born enemies
Cat is a furry pet


df = df[df['cleantext'].str.contains('cat' & 'mouse')].reset_index()
df.shape
```

The above is throwing an error.

I know that for or condition we can write -

```
df = df[df['cleantext'].str.contains('cat | mouse')].reset_index()
```

But I want to extract the rows where both cat and mouse are present

Expected Output -

```
Column
Cat and mouse are the born enemies
```

Comment: If regex, you'd use `(?=.*cat)(?=.*mouse)`

Comment: Thank you, will try this way too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach, which also works for multiple words:

```
words = ['cat', 'mouse']
m = pd.concat([df.Column.str.lower().str.contains(w) for w in words], axis=1).all(1)
df.loc[m,:]

      Column
0  Cat and mouse are the born enemies
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed, it works.

Comment: Thank you for the information :)